# setState does not change data

Tags: reactjs

```
function Foo() {
   const [data, setData] = useState(42);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("SET DATA to 43");
      setData(43);
   }, []);

   function onRefresh() {
      console.log("REFRESH");
      console.log(data);
   }

   return (
     <View>
       <SomeComponent onRefresh={onRefresh} />
       <Text>{data}</Text>
     </View>
   );
}
```

`onRefresh` is called and it shows `42`, but text in ui interface is `43`. Why callback is using old data?

Comment: Remember that effects are for _side effects_, i.e. for doing things that aren't related to your component's state. The reason for this is that effects are going to run _every time render() runs_, and the core behaviour of React is to run render when either props or state updates. So guess what happens if render runs an effect, which updates the state, which causes render to run, which runs your effect, which updates the state, which causes render to run, which runs your effect, which... you get the idea.

Comment: ```data``` is a state or not
if this is a state, it should be ```{this.state.data}```

Comment: @sun1211 that would be true for Class components and its state. Here it's the value of the useState

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In this case the effect will run only on mount as it doesn't have any dependencies.

Comment: @sun1211 Op uses functional component not class base, so he use react hooks

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans does not it run only once on component mount?

Comment: No, citing https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html: "**What does useEffect do?** By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render. React will remember the function you passed (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and call it later after performing the DOM updates." As demonstrated by the comparison of https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-classes with https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks, `useEffect` covers both `componentDidMount` _and_ `componentDidUpdate` for functional components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `useCallback` and give it `data` dependency. Functions in functional components work on the concept of JavaScript closures. They hold the values when defined. We need to tell React to use a new version of the function when the dependency is changed. `useCallback` provides a new function everytime anything in its dependency array is changed.

```
function Foo() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(42);
 
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log("SET DATA to 43");
       setData(43);
    }, []);
 
    const onRefresh = React.useCallback(function onRefresh() {
       console.log("REFRESH");
       console.log(data);
    }, [data]);
 
    return (
      <View>
        <SomeComponent onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </View>
    );
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it helps. Could you describe, please, the solution?